# Auto hide div according to scroll viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have Millions `div` row. I want to add `active` class 7 `div` in scrollbar viewport and remaining all `div` hide. when I scroll active state change according to scrollbar viewport. Items can be Millions in row. I need this for Improve loading time.

https://jsfiddle.net/sapans/afghq58e/3/

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: Below is Example. Items can be in millions.   https://jsfiddle.net/sapans/afghq58e/3/

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
<div class="a">
    A
</div>
```

​

```
.a {
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
background-color: green;
}

$(window).scroll(function() {

if ($(this).scrollTop()>0)
 {
    $('.a').fadeOut();
 }
else
 {
  $('.a').fadeIn();
 }
 });
```

Working example [click here for jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MFUw3/239/)

Comment: Try in this https://jsfiddle.net/sapans/afghq58e/3/  items can millions. i want to do this for optimize loading. All items are hide, when I scroll visibility change according to scroll